# PHP File Upload

Tags: php, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have some code that needs to see if a file has been selected before it runs the code .... its pretty simple code, its just not working for some reason and i cant see why. my code is as follows

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename'])){
$directory = 'uploads/'.substr(md5(microtime() * mktime()),0,15);

if(!is_dir($directory)){
    mkdir($directory, 0777, TRUE);
    chmod($directory, 0777);
}
```

}

I have multiple file fields which are coded like so:

```
<input class="file-input" name="filename[]" type="file" size="32" />
```

When i move the code OUTSIDE the 'if(isset......' block, it works perfect .... just not inside it, and thats where i need it.

Can anyone see where im going wrong?

Comment: `microtime() * mktime()` makes no sense. You are multiplying a string (yes, microtime returns a string unless you use `microtime(true)`) with a number. `md5(microtime())` should be good enough for your purpose. Or have a look at [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear .... I figured the problem.

Yes thats right folks .... I forgot to change the type of form to multipart.

Feel free to throw things at me!!!

Thanks anyways guys!